# Umbraco: How to get rid of "This page is intentionally left ugly"

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

**Help me get rid of the default 400 page**

I've implemented a IContentFinder and added it as a ContentLastChanceFinderResolver. Just like it's explained here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/request-pipeline/icontentfinder

This works flawless!!

**%25c3**

But for certain url's I still see the "This page is intentionally left ugly" system 404 page.

Ex: http://example.com/test%25c3

On umbraco.com just a blank page is returned: https://umbraco.com/test%25c3

How do I get this behaviour?

I've also tried using the configuration-way to set the 404 page, but it still shows the "This page is intentionally left ugly" page.
In /config/umbracoSettings.config:

```
<errors>
    <error404>1105</error404>
</errors>
```

**XSS**

The reason I want to remove the"This page is intentionally left ugly" page is that it allow for cross site scripting attack since it will output what ever you type in the url.

That means if you add a script tag to the url it'll get executed on the "left ugly" page

Comment: Is there a page called test on the site? I.e. does the URL http://example.com/test exist as a page?

Comment: It doesn't matter if "test" exists or not - the behavior is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url `/test%25c3` give a:

HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

Use the IIS error handeling.
In the web.config
place below the `<system.webServer>`

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="11" path="/error.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

And create a error.html file, blank or if you like with some text.

There are many more errors. Try this url for example http://umbraco.com/* or http://umbraco.com/lpt1
more about the error page and a .NET CMS, like Umbraco or Sitecore you can read here: [Sitecore and the error page](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/sitecore-and-the-error-page/) it is also on some Umbraco situations.